# Accessing parent folder + other child folder inside URL, while maintaining server portion

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I have two files with two different URLs, and I want page1 to generate the link to page2. To avoid misunderstandings, this must be solved programmatically in order to maintan consistency, if the domain name changes.

**example urls**
`https://helpdesk.mydomain.com/project1/page1.php`
`https://helpdesk.mydomain.com/project1/page2.php`

**My current code to generate the link to page2 (based on page1's URL)**

```
$server = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$link = $server . "/page2.php";
```

The variable $server contains the portion `https://helpdesk.mydomain.com/project1/`.
In $link, i just concatenate this value with the file name of page2.

**But now**, I'm deciding **to split my main folder** (project1) **into subfolders** (subtask1, subtask2)

`https://helpdesk.mydomain.com/project1/subtask1/page1.php`
`https://helpdesk.mydomain.com/project1/subtask2/page2.php`

**How would I have to adjust my two lines of code as presented above, in order to still reach page2 from the link generated in page1?**

I think I have to use `../` somewhere, but I've never seen this inside an URL...

edit: I cannot use relative links, because the link which is generated, is sent to someone via email. The link has to contain the full URL

Thanks

Comment: I actually had a further think about your question and came up with a much better solution in my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use [dirname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php):

```
dirname($path);
```

i.e.

```
dirname('helpdesk.mydomain.com/project1/page1.php');
```

Should give: `helpdesk.mydomain.com/project1`, and

```
dirname('helpdesk.mydomain.com/project1')
```

Should give `helpdesk.mydomain.com`

#### Edit

I actually thought about this a little more and came up with the following function:

```
function up_folder($path, $depth = 1){
    for ($i=0; $i < $depth; $i++) { 
        $path = dirname($path);
    }
    return $path;
}
```

Using this you can do something along the lines of this:

```
$path = 'https://helpdesk.mydomain.com/project1/subtask1/page1.php';

echo up_folder($path);
echo up_folder($path, 2);
echo up_folder($path, 3);
echo up_folder($path, 4);
```

This will output the following:

- https://helpdesk.mydomain.com/project1/subtask1
- https://helpdesk.mydomain.com/project1
- https://helpdesk.mydomain.com
- https:

Comment: You forgot the /subtask/ but I think this looks good. Giving it a try

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that structure example is the actual use case all you need is two links like this.

```
<a href="../subtask2/page2.php">This link goes on page 1</a>
<a href="../subtask1/page1.php">This link goes on page 2</a>
```

Those are relative links, you can read more about them here.  http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: I can't use relative links, because the link which is generated, is sent to someone via email. I'm adding this to the question right now.

Comment: Check out my other answer

Answer (score 0):

With that edit in mind you might want to try something like this. WARNING: Untested code :)

```
$server = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$suffix = dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$bits = explode($suffix, "/");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($bits) - 1; $i++) {
    $server = $server . $bits[$i] . "/";
}
$server = $server . "subtask1/task1.php";
// OR
// $server = $server . "subtask2/task2.php";
```

Comment: I just tried typing in `https://helpdesk.mydomain.com/project1/subtask1/../subtask2/page2.php` and it actually worked... Seems easier than your answer but I'm not sure if this ../ inside the URL is a good practice

Comment: In the middle of the URL, not a great plan :P